# Javascript Game Level Collision

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently in the process of writing my first game and am doing it in Javascript+HTML5 Canvas. The game is a top down point-click action shooter with WASD movement. Anyway, yesterday I finished implementing collision detection using circles and a quad-tree to minimize the comparisons. I throw all the bullets, players, and enemies into the quadtree. Now, that all is working fine, but I am unsure of how to handle the next step which is handling the collision on the actual level. Bullets should be blocked by walls, actors (player and enemies) should be blocked by both fences and walls, etc.

Should I define shapes to represent the walls of my level and include them as a form of object within the quadtree then use the SAT to evaluate each of the elements against anything that it may be colliding with or is there another way like creating a hidden image layer that outlines the path and then test each object's coordinates to make sure it doesn't land on a black pixel (which would indicate that it is colliding with the unmoving terrain)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a similar question:

> I suggest reading this excellent article about how ghost movement and
>   collision detection works in [PacMan](http://gameinternals.com/post/2072558330/understanding-pac-man-ghost-behavior?ba0efa20).
>
> Then I would suggest logically modeling your Bomberman levels as a
>   collection of tiles. Each tile represents a discrete position in your
>   level, and it is not logically possible to ever be "between" tiles or
>   occupying two tiles at the same time. Each tile can track what sort of
>   terrain feature is currently on it, and whether or not it is a valid
>   destination tile for the player (and the enemies, potentially with
>   different rules for each if the enemies are allowed to traverse
>   terrain that is normally impassable for the player).
>
> Then you don't need a collision detection algorithm for every object
>   in the world. When it comes time for an enemy to move, or when the
>   user tries to move their character, all you have to do is check all
>   the tiles that are adjacent to their current tile (4, or 8 max if you
>   allow diagonal movement), see if each tile represents a valid movement
>   direction, and block the movement if it is not in a valid direction.
>
> And to answer your question, yes, iterating every object in the world
>   on every position update will be very inefficient.

Comment: I don't think that would work for me, as I want the actors to be able to move in a full 360 degrees, same with the bullets and the angles they shoot. Thus, I couldn't really do any sort of tile based system because you would constantly need to be between tiles.

Comment: You'll just want to make your tiles smaller :) Most SNES games are tile based so you can definitely do a lot with it, see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcKJ6tYvvq0. Also, just because the world is tile based doesn't mean characters always have to appear exactly on one tile.

Comment: So basically the tiles act as a way for me to keep tract of the player's position and when a player tries to move into a new tile, I check to see if that title is a moveable tile. If it isn't I perform a calculation to allow the player to move right up to the edge of that tile, but not all the way through. And I represent the tiles as an multi-array, right?

Comment: Then I could represent the tiles as sections of say 10 px. A 35 pixel circle would take up at least 4 by 4 tiles at a time and if the circle moves into a tile represented with a 1, I continue to let it move till hit hits the x of 30 which would be the edge of that one tile.

Comment: Yep, that's the basic idea. You just want to make your tile size the same size as the smallest element that you need to place on it. Larger elements just take up more tiles.